# Syntax for passing form selection into jquery/colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I have a HTML form that calls a php file, this in turns returns the output of a mysql SELECT query based on what the user submitted in the form. This is all working correctly, resolved some minor issue with the help of this forum.

Now what I want to do this have the result of the php displayed inside a jquery/colorbox popup. However, it seems the jquery is just loading the php file that is my action="verify.php" , it is not actually passing the selected variable. I know this because I set the SELECT statement to a constant query and it displayed correctly. 
When setting the php to use the POSTed variables, the result is blank.

I have never used jquery/colorbox before , so I assume I am doing something wrong here.
Could someone tell me how to resolve this before I go mental ?

jquery/colorbox

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
                $("input#formsubmit").colorbox({href: function(){
    var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');
    return url;
}, innerWidth:920, innerHeight:"86%", iframe:true});                
            });
```

The code for the form ...

```
<form name="form" action="verify.php" method="post">

<select name="product">

<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("verify") or die(mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT ProductName FROM products");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"". $row['ProductName'] ."\">". $row['ProductName'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<select name="customer">


<option value="End User">End User</option>
<option value="Partner">Partner</option>

</select>

<input type="submit" name="Update" id="formsubmit" value="Verify">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the user selected variable to your url. Right now you are doing this

```
 var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');
```

Which probably results in url being set to just the value of the action attribute. You need to append the user selected variable to the end of it. So something like

```
var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action')+"&yourvarvalue="+getUserSelectedVariable(this);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding ... can you tell me how ? I am completely new to this ... thanks.

Comment: How are you defining the input element where the user can choose a variable? You basically need to grab that elements value. For e.g. if you have an element defined like this <input id="variableid" type="text" value="some text"/> then you can grab the value using $( "#variableid").val(). So your url will look like var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action')+"&yourvarvalue="+$("#variableid").val()

Comment: Hi, within the form I have two dropdown menus, one is populated from a mysql DB and the other has 2 options , added the code above

Comment: I still don't see the HTML where the dropdowns are defined, can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: I am a little fuzzy on your requirements. Your php code executes before the page gets loaded. So when the HTML is rendered you will have two drop downs. If you want to take the user selected drop down values and then return something else based on those selections, you need to have a URL on your server side which will accept these parameters and return a payload which can be displayed in the color box. When your server encounters the 'verify' URI, what does it do?

Comment: Also, you can grab the user selected value using something like this $('select[name="customer"]').val().

Comment: When I click submit on my form the colorbox pops up and the verify.php loads inside this. If the verify.php contains static variables for the query it loads correctly inside the colorbox. However I want the user selected variable from the dropdown to be passed to the verify.php

Comment: When the server encounters the verify.php the user selected variables are added to a sql SELECT statement and the result is displayed.

Comment: OK, so what you have to do is something like this var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action')+"&productname="+$('select[name="product"]').val() + "&customertype=" + $('select[name="customer"]').val(); Substitute the variable names appropriately. I just guessed your variable names will be productname and customertype

Comment: Just to clarify, "&ProductName=" is the column name in my DB ? And 'select[name="product"]' is the selection from the drop down ?

Comment: Actually just test the above and now I am getting "Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server." If I remove +"&ProductName="+$('select[name="product"]').val() + "&CustomerType=" + $('select[name="customer"]').val() I get the verify.php page loading (no output though as before because no variables where passed)

Comment: ProductName and CustomerType are the variables that your server expects. I just made them up for the example, replace them as needed. The $ are the jquery selectors that give you the drop down values. Print out the url variable (console.log or alert it out) and see what gets constructed and then directly hit that URL on the browser, see what you get back from your server.

Comment: It seems the correct variables are being passed, but its returning a 404 error for some reason. javascript console shows this verify.php&ProductName=New%20product1&CustomerType=End%20User 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I cannot access localhost/verify/verify.php&ProductName=New%20product1&CustomerType=End%20User directly , this seems to be the problem. Thanks for all your help so far

Comment: Well, seems like your server does not like that URL or the parameters. Now you need to move your debugging to the server side, find out why you server doesnt like that URL.

Comment: Should accessing the php from the URL not be something like verify.php? ... the above has no '?'

Comment: Yeap...you need the ?. I missed it in my example.